# Typescript: create a method, returning the type of which was determined depending on the class

Tags: typescript

I want to set a method in the parent class, the return value of which would be determined depending on the type of the `value` field.

```
class A {
   protected value: string;
   public getValue(): this['value'] { .... }
}

class B extends A {
   protected value: number;
}

new B().getValue() - should be a number
```

How can I do this? I tried to do it as shown above, but it doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like you want generics `class A<T> { value: T; getValue(): T }`

Comment: This comment should be the answer. @VLAZ

Comment: @VLAZ The problem is that I want to leave the exact definition for the class that if you create class A, then it can only have a value with `number` type, and if class B - then only a `string` type. 
Does this mean that I need to create a parent class for classes A and B, in which all methods will be implemented, and in the inherited classes A and B, already determine the type for value?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgHgBUA+BAbwCgEqAHKAewh3hwBMFRIZ4EA3YZAK44AXAgIBuSlQDmOCADV+QgBQBKUQTIIocgVAB2CCAAsAlmAB0fQTgQBfcg-Io0GAIIIcAD0b6WGbDB8TlN9aRIKKl4lWwBeBAByBMknF3QsTx8cPwDcPH0BAFsQHCgIqWibBHiARgAmAGYU8nJ9HAB3LDULWQUYtSA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic classes/ functions from typescript to solve this.

```
class A<T> { value: T; getValue(): T }
```

You can read about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Your answer could best be qualified as a comment as you are not really solving the problem rather you are showing a general direction to approach.